# Find length from portion of string up to a certain char

Tags: sql, db2

DB2 SQL => How to get the length from the portion of a string? For example, data for this column are

```
MARYqORANGE
JENNYqBLUE,
DAVEqYELLOW,
JONATHANqGREEN 
AMANDAqBLACK
```

How can I get the length for these data before `q`?

Comment: ... This is a multi-value/delimited column.  This are _really_ heavily frowned upon (for needing to do this, among other things) - you're aware of that, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `locate` function:

```
select locate('q', col)
```

If you want the initial part before the 'q', then use:

```
select (case when col like '%q%' then left(col, locate('q', col) - 1) else col end)
```